# Passing limit GET parameter directly to MySQL security issue?

Tags: mysql, security, limit, dos

I'd like to know if it's a security risk to have an URL similar to the following

http://www.mytestapp.com/results?limit=1234

The limit GET parameter would then be checked as valid integer and passed directly into a query.

What would happen if an user changed this parameter to a very large number? For a huge database would that cause an effect similar to denial of service?

What is the best practice for having a variable result limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just pass the GET variable directly into your query. If you did, then I could do SQL injection like this:

```
http://www.mytestapp.com/results?limit=1%3BDROP%20TABLE%20USERS
```

And your query would end up looking like:

```
select * from some_table where parameter = 3 limit 1;DROP TABLE USERS
```

I'm assuming you're trying to do paging. If so, you'll want to have something like:

```
http://www.mytestapp.com/results?page=1&size=10
```

Then, on your backend, verify that `page` and `size` are both integers, and both of a reasonable size. Maybe set limits on what `size` can be, perhaps only multiples of 10 up to 100, for example.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Setting limits on the size is considered applying a [whitelist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist), which is a good security measure. Letting the users tell you what they want is fine, but only let them do what they are allowed to do, regardless of what they ask for.

Comment: I'm still validating the get parameter. It needs to be integer, so ?limit=1%3BDROP%20TABLE%20USERS wouldn't work because "1;DROP TABLE USERS" isn't numeric.

Comment: Still, what would happen to the site if the user provided for instance "18446744073709551615" as the limit parameter?
On a huge database would the select query use up all of MySQL resources and freeze the entire site?

Comment: The point is that you can't trust input from the user, ever. Suppose you are parsing it as an integer. Now suppose the user requested `LIMIT=1`, then `LIMIT=2`, `LIMIT=3` repeatedly (so as to break your query cache). You're then vulnerable to a DoS attack, as MySQL re-runs the same query over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem with passing parameters in get strings is it can open you up to sql injection attacks. What if someone passes this:

> http://www.mytestapp.com/results?limit=1234;drop table users;

You need to carefully watch to make sure you sanitize your inputs.

Assuming you have been intelligent about that and understand the security, then the other issue is that it puts your limits in the hands of the end user. They could effectively remove the limit by using a very large number. Depending on the complexity of your queries and the size of your tables, this could negatively impact your server performance and other users.

I am not aware with any other issues due to a large number in the limit clause. I don't think you'll need to worry about an overflow, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As others have set, validate the input before you pass it on to the database, to make sure it's an integer, does not contain anything besides digits, and is of a reasonable size value. For this case, you will effectively prevent SQL Injection.

You also should not be building query strings by concatenating your command logic with parameters from untrusted sources. You should be making use of parametrized queries, where you identify where data fits into the SQL statement when you create it and then bind the value in later. This has the effect of allowing the database to differentiate what you intend to be command what you intend to be data, preventing SQL Injection even if you miss an attack case in your input validation (for this particular case, the whitelist is easy...this is not always true or even possible). You can read more about parametrized queries on the well-written [OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) page.